# Scope not updating on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html

```
 <div ng-controller="data">
       <div class="main">
           <div>{{name}}</div>
           <div custom-tag>click</div>
       </div></br>
       <div class="main">
           <div>{{name}}</div>
           <div custom-tag>click</div>
       </div></br>
       <div class="main">
           <div>{{name}}</div>
           <div custom-tag>click</div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

When i click on particular div (click div) , I want to chage the name into above div of the particular clicked div .

This is my controller

```
 app.controller('data',function($scope)
 {
     $scope.name="john"

 });
```

So when I load my html page it will be shown like this

```
 John
 click

 john
 click

 john
 click
```

When I click on first click , I have to change name to britto so out put should be like this

```
 Britto 
 click

 john
 click

 john
 click
```

This is my directive i have tried like this. When I click on div I am getting alert message that clicked . But scope is not changed the name

```
 app.directive('customTag',function()
{
       return function(scope, element, attrs)
       {
         element.bind('click',function()
         {
           alert("clicked");
           scope.name="britto"

         });
       }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the scope that you made changes, seeing as you're updating the scope outside of angular.

Like this.

```
element.bind('click',function(){
   alert("clicked");
   scope.name = "britto"
   scope.$apply();
});
```

You can also do this.

```
element.bind('click',function(){
   alert("clicked");
   scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.name = "britto"
   });
});
```

I'm not entirely sure what the difference is...

A good way to help remember this is to remember that any function that is not called by angular.js and is out of the program flow you need to use `scope.$apply();` whenever making changes to the scope, so `click` would be out of the flow because it can be triggered at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:   You have to call **scope.$apply()** after you change the scope, as the "click" isn't "angular-aware".

It'll work, but there are much better way to do what you're after:
A.  Use ng-click,  and skip the directive

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
<div ng-click="changeName()">click</div>
```

Then add to your controller:

```
$scope.changeName = function(){ $scope.name="britto"; }
```

B.  Directives and scopes: You should really take the time and read through [this documentation page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
You can jump directly to: "**Isolating the Scope of a Directive**" section

---- (EDIT) ----
C.  Using **ng-repeat**

controller:

```
$scope.names = ["john","michael","jack"];
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="data">
   <div class="main" ng-repeat="name in names">
       <div>{{name}}</div>
       <div ng-click="name='britto'">click</div>
       <br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e92rDvDSiM9SWVN298Ad?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply .but if i follow your answer the name(britto) will be updated to all div(that means name will come three times as per my question).....

Comment: Yes,  they all share the **same** scope, hence "name" variable is same.   see this documentation:  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.    I've edited the answer to offer you a better way...